# icon not change in device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

For the icon change  effect on the android emulator and device if i install manually .apk .ipa file . It works fine after changing the application icon and uploaded  mobilefirst console in the production environment.

but problem is marketing manager mail me . application updated but not changed the Application icon in iOS and android device.

at this situation what can i do ?

I flowing this 
[link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_application_resources.html)

[image: emulatio]

Comment: So I am guessing what you're actually saying is: 1) you are using mobilefirst appcenter 2) you have an existing app installed via appcenter. You changed the app icon but the app icon does not change in the installed application. Did you try to first remove the app and then re-add it?

Comment: no , I just changed app icon and upload it in application console .

Comment: So why would it change in the device? You need to install the app again.

Comment: so I have to send a update  application link(app center)  for all user and first remove the old app and then re-add it.

Comment: If you changed the app icon, you must update the app on the device. That is a Native resource.

Comment: update and install the app again not same . what i force to my user update or install again ?

Comment: Both will have the same effect. You need to test first - test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106880/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-idan-adar).

Comment: 1) Change app icon native section 2)app environment uploaded application console 3)application updated in my android device. But not change in my app icon .

Comment: Did you re-build the .apk and uploaded it to the **appcenter** console? Did you then update the application in the device? if yes, then remove the app and download again. Does it work then? If not, you did not really update the icon. Did it work in your test environment (directly from eclipse to device)?

Comment: if i remove the app and download again it work.but it is not good  way . better update ,that is  not work for me .

Comment: How are you updating the app on the device? via the appcenter installer app?

Comment: 1)not increment the app version number
2)Build and generate a new .wlapp file 
3)Deploy the new .wlapp file to Worklight Server 4) remove the app and then re-add in app center

Comment: I think you must increment the version number. Otherwise it will not do an update....

Comment: now it has changed. thanks, you can prompt answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, an update will not take place if you did not increment the version number of the application.

If you change a native resource such as the app icon, but do not increment the application version number then the check for a new version will not see the update because it is basing it on the version number.

Update the version number and upload the updated .apk and .ipa; the update should then happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me whether you refer to the icon that you see on the device home screen or to the icon that you see in the AppCenter console.

The icon on the home screen is managed by the device OS, and Idan's answer is correct here. This effect has nothing to do with IBM AppCenter but rather with the device OS.

The icon in the IBM AppCenter console is cached for 30 minutes in the browser, in order to allow the browser to refresh the screen more quickly. The idea is that icons change rarely and speed it important. There is a Java VM property **ibm.appcenter.services.iconCacheMaxAge** (in seconds) that can be set to a different value to modify this effect.